# Push view controller after setting view

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller

Suppose i have a uiview in 1 screen and i want to view the same view in fullscreen mode on click of a button.

On click of a button the following function is called.

```
-(IBAction)fullScreen
{
  FullScreenViewController *mv = [[FullScreenViewController alloc] init];
  mv.fullview = minimizedView; 

  //minimizedView is a UIView already created with a specified frame
  // fullview is a UIView decalred in FullScreenViewController

  [[self navigationController] pushViewController:mv  animated:YES]; 

}
```

In the FullScreenViewController.m the viewDidLoad function is as follows :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [self.view addSubview:fullview];

}
```

On click of the fullscreen button, the view appears but on click of back button, the minimized view in the previous page dissapears.

Is it wrong to do this?

Comment: While you click the button you have to change the frame size of your UIview which is inside and you have to resize it when you click cancel option.Use animation to get a better result.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use two views to implement this. In your code, your are navigating from one view to another view. You dont need to do that. Your minimizeView itself having a property "setFrame:" to increase and decrease its frame to resize of that subview in your current view itself. Learn how to resize the UIView.